# AWS RDS postgresql dblink could not establish connection

Tags: amazon-rds

I have AWS RDS postgresql(13.7) and I'm trying to create dblink to another RDS postgresql(same version).

```
create server pg_rep_db foreign data wrapper dblink_fdw options(host 'XXXX.rds.amazonaws.com', dbname 'my_db_name', port '5432');
```

Both RDS instances are running on the same subnet.
Although, I've added inbound rule, still unable to establish connection.

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "XXXX.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.64.4.XXX) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Internal IP of Both RDS is 172.64.4.XXX and the in-bound rule of secrity group likes below.

```
PostgreSQL  TCP 5432    172.64.4.0/24   pg_transport
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you what rules you have added in the security groups attached to both the rds instances?

Comment: I made the post updated.